# PHP automatically loop through pagination

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code and function that I call a API url with and return data as an array using json_decode. Problem is that the data returned comes paginated. Therefore, with the result of the page i get a array key called nextPageID. So when I make the call using the function I can only get the first set of data from the first page. Is there a way for me to loop the function until nextPageID parameter is no longer defined?

```
$getData = getData("https://api.url/api?key=xyz");
$next_pageid = $getData['nextPageID'];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($getData);
echo "</pre>";


function getData($url){
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    return json_decode($json,true);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the API documentation?

Comment: What about checking for that parameter and run another API call?

Comment: *"Is there a way"* - Yes.  What have you tried and where are you stuck?  I imagine at a high level your steps would be to deserialize the response into an object and examine it.  If it indicates that there are more results available, make another request and deserialize that and combine its data with the data you have.

Comment: Just surround your code (not the function) with a while loop: `do { ....<your code> ....} while (isset($getData['nextPageID']));` And use the next index, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use recursion - call function in function. On example:

```
$api_url = "https://api.url/api?key=xyz";
function getData($api){
    $json = file_get_contents($api);
    $array = json_decode($json);
    //This is ok ONLY if on last page nextPageID = null and for get next page you need to use parametr nextPageID in GET
    if(isset($array['nextPageID']) && $array['nextPageID'] !== null){
        $array .= array_merge($array,(getData($api."&nextPageID=".$array['nextPageID']));
    }
    return $array;
}
print_r (getData($api_url));
```